# Is possible to setup federation from code?

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, alpakka

Is it possible to setup federation using pure AMQP protocol/headers? Right now I'm using REST API to setup federation and un-federate an autogenerated queue which is a bit cumbersome.

Update:
I'm using RabbitMQ 3.7.8 which is AMQP version 0.9 of the protocol

Comment: First of all, you should specify what version of protocol do you use? The 1.0 version is completely different from 0.X version on the conceptual level.

In RabbitMQ (AMQP 0.9) my best effort in such scenarios was to use CLI admin tool at build/deploy time.

Comment: Thanks, updated the question. Right now we are using a REST API to create federation as this is happening for autogenerated queues so build/deploy time won't work. The main problem is with cleaning up the federation.